# Angular2 & ngbootstrap Datepicker and the NavigateTo() function

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

In this plnkr (provided by bootstrap), they use a button to call the navigateTo() function.  This resets the focus in the calendar to either the current month, or the month of their choosing, depending on whether they send the year and month with it.

http://embed.plnkr.co/wC4XeI8OOIBAMLo9yeFc/

How do I do that programatically in my .ts file?

```
myapp.ts
dp: NgbDatepicker;
model: NgbDateStruct;

onClick() // from a button for temporary testing
{
  this.dp.navigateTo (); // Cannot read property 'navigateTo' of undefined
  this.model = {year: 2017, month: 10, day: 3}; // this selects the date properly
}
```

vsCode has the correct code hints when I type this.dp.navigateTo, it just doesn't work.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you share template html code?

Comment: Solved: Need to add @Viewchild('dp') dp: any;  then I can use this.dp.navigateTo();

Comment: template code is the same as the plnkr from bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

You do this with the help of @ViewChild decorator

```
@ViewChild( 'dp') dp;
this.dp.navigateTo({year: 2018, month: 2});
```